# Tracking wget requests

Tags: apache, web, wget

I'm wondering if there's any way to track all the wget requests that I've made while developing my server.

Is there any way to do this?

I'm running an apache server. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all requests to your web server (apache) in the access.log file.
It's usually in the /var/log/httpd/access.log (on redhat-based distributions)

Comment: Additionally, `/var/log/apache2/access.log` is typically the access log for debian-based distros.